# python statsmodels arima prediction real data option

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

I am probably just misunderstanding the docs, but how do I use the ARIMAResults.predict function on new data?  I created a model on a training data set, and now I'd like to see how it performs on my test set, so I need to run something like `result.predict(test_data, steps=3)`

**EDIT:** Perhaps the question was too vague.  This is a more specific thing that I could generalize from:...

Suppose I get an ARIMA model:

```
model = sm.tsa.ARIMA(train_data, (1, 0, 0)).fit(disp=0)
```

I would now like to see how well the parameters of this model perform on some `test_data` that I have set aside.  Viz. given `test_data[0:50]`, predict `test_data[52]`; given `test_data[1:51]` predict `test_data[53]` etc etc.  Note that I do *not* want to train an ARIMA model on `test_data`, I just want to use the parameters from `model` to evaluate performance.

Answer (score 0):

This basic code should work.  For example, this will predict 50 periods after the end of your in sample period.  I use integer index values in case you have data that doesn't have equal intervals (minute stock prices over multiple days for example), but if that's not the case you can use time periods as well.

```
start_idx = len(df.loc[start:end].index) - 1
pred_length = 50 

model = sm.tsa.ARIMA(df.loc[start:end], (1, 0, 0)).fit(disp=0)
predict = model.predict(start_idx, start_idx + pred_length)
print(predict)
```